# defmacro not defined in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

I'm trying to use `defmacro` in ClojureScript, but I'm getting a console error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'crd.core.defmacro.call')
```

Here's the test code that's generating the error:

```
(ns crd.core)

(defmacro t [] `())
```

And the generated JavaScript code:

```
goog.provide('crd.core');
goog.require('cljs.core');
crd.core.defmacro.call(null,crd.core.t,cljs.core.Vector.fromArray([]),null);
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: defmacro requires 4 arguments. see here: http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/defmacro

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `doc-string` and `attr-map` are optional, which just leaves `name`, `[params*]`, and `body`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My failure: I didn't read [Differences from Clojure](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure). ClojureScript does support macros, but only in .clj files that are imported with `require-macros`.